# How to use GetStorage to store a Set

Tags: flutter

I am using [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) to store `List`, and it works fine, but I wonder if it is possible to use the same way with `Set`, since `Set` has few advantages over `List`,

This is the method that I am using to write and read with `List`:

```
var box = GetStorage();

List<int> listInt = [1, 2, 3];

// Write
box.write('listInt', listInt);
// Read
List<int> a = box.read('listInt')?.cast<int>() ?? [];
List<int> readList = a.toList();
```

And here is `Set`, please help me if it is possible

`Set<int> setInt = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: Which kind of database do you use?

Comment: I just use GetStorage to save local file in device

Comment: you need to mention that you are using the package `get_storage`. Why you don't simply convert your list to Set?

Comment: ye, my bad, edited, thanks. Yup, I know it is possible to do so but will need to use `toList()` before write and convert back to `toSet()` after read. So I was curious if there is a way to write `Set` directly